# SublimeText EsLint issues- cannot be located

Tags: sublimetext, sublimelinter

`nvm` does not play nicely with eslint/sublime. I tirelessly tried to configure this with different paths/plugins.

Various errors come out- such as `.bin/eslint: line 2: sed: command not found`, `eslint cannot locate 'eslint'` and more

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. The code should be a [mre]. Make sure you post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Answer (score 0):

My solution?

Make sure to install both `SublimeLinter` and `SublimeLinter-eslint`

As your node package manager, use `volta`. Run `npm install -g eslint` and voilia!

Your config should look like this:

```
{
    "linters": {
        "eslint": {
            "disable": false,
            "args": ["--env=es6"],
            "env": {
               "PATH": "/Users/[USER_NAME]/.volta/tools/image/node/18.16.0/bin"
            }
        }
    }
}
```